# How can I use the hat symbol to negate a character which is at the start of my regex in Scite?

Tags: regex, scite

In the Scite editor is there a way to runa regex search where the first character is "notted".

Normally the hat symbol (^) is used but at the start of the regex this indicates the start of a line.

So this:

```
^.', +'default'
```

Doesn't work (this sequence can be in the middle of a line). :-(

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can. A quick read of the documentation and square braces come to the rescue:

```
[^.]', +'default'
```

Comment: This is fairly typical regex engine behavior.  I think you should have only opened this question if you discovered something else helpful about the Scite regex API.

Comment: I thought it was useful - that's why I added the question.